# Laravel API returns weird characters like a "space" and new line "\n"

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-sanctum

I have to post this so every newbie like me who encounters the same problem will have a soln.
I have a weird return response from my Laravel API as shown in the image:
[image]

as you can see, there is a space and a new line "\n" in my token response. I have no idea where to find it since all my controllers and the one where the token exists, don't have space on it.

So I was searching on the internet and there are no clues or results I found not atleast one.

Answer (score 0):

**Fix**: I found that in my web.php, I accidentally spaced and entered and then saved the file, and that's it. So whenever you find weird results in your return response, kindly check your web.php or API.